# Could somebody assist with doing API calls with 'httr' package in R?

Tags: r, api, curl, httr

I tried to do a API call to get data from a website called [BirdEye](https://developers.birdeye.com/#/reference/reviews/get/get-reviews). They have a developer website with instructions on API calls. However, I am having trouble converting curl code into R code using httr package.

Example:

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -H "accept:application/json" -X POST -d { "fromDate":"04/01/2013", "toDate":"05/3/2015", "updateFromDate":"04/01/2013", "updateToDate":"05/3/2015", "sources":["google","citysearch"], "ratings":[1,2,3,4,5,0],"searchStr":"Awesome","subBusinessIds":[145308764185002,145308769721320,145308702026610],"tags":["tag_1","tag_2"] } "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/review/businessId/755009344_1?sindex=0&count=25&api_key=92bcd6e0-c102-43fd-8a67-1a7be5258451" -v
```

Here is what I did:

```
headers <- c('Accept' = 'application/json', 'Content-Type' = 'application/json')

body_content <- list('fromDate' = '2019-01-01', 'toDate' = '2019-05-01', 'sources' = 'google', 'ratings' = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0))

resp <- POST(url ="https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/review/businessId/xxxxxxxxxx?sindex=0&count=20&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
             body = body_content, content_type("application/json"), accept("application/json"))
```

But I got an error message below:

```
Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value

Warning message:
In charToRaw(enc2utf8(val)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

Could someone help with the issue? Appreciate it!